# jQuery event on Non dom element. (like ajaxComplete behavior)

Tags: jquery

I want to create a behavior similar to the event ajaxComplete that is triggered after each Ajax request, no matter what, no matter on each Dom element or not it's done.

I used that code that I took for Jquery core code

```
// Attach a bunch of functions for handling common AJAX events
jQuery.each("openEtFoldingFieldset closeEtFoldingFieldset".split(" "), function(i, o) {
    jQuery.fn[o] = function(f) {
        return jQuery.fn.on(o, f);
    };
```

in my plugin i trigger the openEtFoldingFieldset event

```
var etFoldingFieldsetOpenEvent = jQuery.Event("openEtFoldingssFieldset");
jQuery.fn.trigger(etFoldingFieldsetOpenEvent);
```

in my page script, i try to add an handle for the trigger like that

```
$('.log').openEtFoldingFieldset(function() {
    alert("folding open");
    return true;
});
```

Like i did for the ajaxComplete

```
$('.log').ajaxComplete(function() {
    $(this).text('Triggered ajaxComplete handler.');
})
```

I don't get any error, the function openEtFoldingFieldset, is correctly recognized by jQuery, but the function is never called.

Hope some can help me on that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For any event handler you create yourself you'll need to use `bind()` (or `on()` if you using jQ 1.7). This is because handlers like `click()` and `keyup()` etc are shortcuts in the jQuery source to `bind("eventName", fn)` (or in jQuery 1.7+ `on("eventName", fn)`). You can't simply create an event, and use it as a function on a jQuery object.

With that in mind, try this:

```
$('.log').bind("openEtFoldingFieldset", function() {
    alert("folding open");
    return true;
});
```